# Webpack 4 build bricks CSP with unsafe-eval

Tags: typescript, webpack, content-security-policy

When I try to execute my TypeScript + React Webpack 4 app, the code gets not executed with an error:

Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'

However, in the generated bundle, I find the following passage in line 1:

```
/* [...] */ get(e,t,n)}},_=Function("return this")(),C=new Map([[Map,T],[Set,T],[ /* [...] */
```

This is, of course, promply executed, leading to the above error.

From what I can tell, something seems to require a reference to the global object (aka `window`), and try to get it by invoking `Function("return this")()`.

Indeed, if I change the generated `app.<hash>.js` and replace the `,_=Function("return this")()` with a simple `,_=window` everything works, and there aren't any CSP complaints.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --port 1234 --hot --inline --mode=development",
    "dev-twitch": "webpack-dev-server --port 1235 --hot --inline --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "build-dev": "webpack -d"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.12.12",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^2.0.15",
    "autobind-decorator": "^2.3.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-easy-state": "^6.0.6",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
    "zip-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const ZipPlugin = require('zip-webpack-plugin');

const htmlPlugins = [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    inject: 'body',
    filename: 'index.html',
    chunks: ['app'],
  }),
];

let appIndex = './src/ts/_entry.tsx';
let outDir = 'dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
  const devMode = process.argv.find(v => v.includes('webpack-dev-server'));

  const styleLoader = devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader;
  const cssPlugins = [];
  if (!devMode) {
    cssPlugins.push(
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].[hash].css',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].css',
      })
    );
  }

  return ({
    entry: {
      app: appIndex,
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, outDir),
      filename:  '[name].[hash].js'
    }, resolve: {
      // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
      alias: {
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
      }
    },
    devtool: 'hidden-source-map',
    node: {
      global: false,
    },
    plugins: [
      ...htmlPlugins,
      ...cssPlugins,
      new CleanWebpackPlugin('./' + outDir),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: './src/assets',
        to: './assets/'
      }]),
      new ZipPlugin({
        filename: 'dist-twitch.zip',
        path: __dirname,
      }),
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: 'ts-loader' },
        { test: /\.(svg|woff|ttf|eot|woff2|otf)$/, use: 'file-loader' },
        { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/, use: 'file-loader' },
        { test: /\.scss$/, use: [styleLoader, 'css-loader','sass-loader'] },
        { test: /\.css$/, use: [styleLoader, 'css-loader'] },
      ]
    },
    devServer: {
      clientLogLevel: 'error',
      overlay: true,
      proxy: {
        '/join': 'http://localhost',
      },
    }
  });
}
```

How can I modify the build so I don't have to manually touch the results? How can I best find out what module is responsible for the bad code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the culprit was `@nx-js/observer-util` required by `react-easy-state`.

I have written a [pull request](https://github.com/nx-js/observer-util/pull/39) which should fix the problem.

Comment: How did you discover it was this package? I'm having the same problem, but do not have either of these packages included and am struggling to find the culprit

Answer (score 9):

I resolved the issue by adding 'devtool: "source-map"' to my config. Please see below.

```
const clientConfig = {
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'web',
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      ...
    },
    module: {
       rules: [
          ...
       ],
    },
    output: {
       ...
    },
    resolve: {
       ...
    } 
}

module.exports = [clientConfig]
```

I discovered this solution [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5627#issuecomment-374386048).